# Direction of induced voltage of a magnetic flux

Tags: magnetic-fields

Given the magnetic flux $\phi$, I would like to calculate the induced voltage $v$. I know that $v=-N\frac{d\phi}{dt}$. How can I find the sign of the voltage?

[image]

Comment: "Energy can neither be created or destroyed", when a magnet is pushed into the coil it resists the push in, and when it is pulled out it resists the pull out, which induces an electric current in a closed circuit and an induced voltage in an open circuit due to the rate of change of flux linkage (Faraday's law), the reason for the negative is given by Lenz's law, which coincides with the principle of energy conservation.

Answer (score 2):

The direction or "sense" of the voltage generated is such that any resulting current produces a magnetic field opposing the change in magnetic field which created it. This is the meaning of the minus sign in Faraday's Law, and it is called Lenz's law.